# How to show progress when converting documents using libreoffice

Tags: pdf, progress-bar, exec, libreoffice, soffice

When I convert documents using libreoffice on server. It takes a long time to process. I need to know progress to response to front end. But I don't find any info about progress of this conversion. I also try as below when converting doc to pdf:

```
exec("soffice --headless --convert-to pdf $oriFile --outdir $outputDirectory 1> block.txt 2>&1");
```

But in file block.txt is blank. It was not written anything about processing.

Anyone please help. Thanks!

Comment: anybody give me some advice?

Comment: Hi, did you resolve this?